# Colocar dados de uma linha em colunas

Tags: php, sql, sql-server, pivot

```
SELECT datacc, horacc
FROM R070ACC WITH (NOLOCK) 
WHERE numcad = '2676' AND DATACC between ('2018-16-04') and ('2018-15-05') and oriacc = 'E'
```

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Na primeira coluna aparece o dia do mês repetido 4x, com registros diferentes na segunda coluna referente a essa data.  (ANEXO 01)

Como faço para o dia ficar na primeira coluna e criar 4 colunas para os registros referente a esse mesmo dia?

Exemplo:

```
DATA                  REG1                 REG2              REG3                  REG4

2018-04-16            723                  425               783                      1040

2018-04-17            733                  793               1075                     423
```

Comment: Você quer fazer isso para exibir em quatro colunas? Ou organizar o backend com 4 colunas?

Comment: Além da coluna DATACC, existe outra coluna que informe a sequência em que as linhas devem ser lidas, para uma mesma data?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Eis sugestão que utiliza o pivô clássico para gerar as 4 colunas.

```
-- código #1 v3
with R070ACCseq as (
SELECT numcad, datacc, horacc,
       seq= row_number() over (partition by numcad, cast(datacc as date) 
                               order by (SELECT 0))
  from R070ACC 
  where datacc between '2018-04-16' and '2018-05-15'
        and numcad = '2676' 
        and oriacc = 'E'
)
SELECT numcad, datacc, 
       max(case when seq = 1 then horacc end) as REG1,
       max(case when seq = 2 then horacc end) as REG2,
       max(case when seq = 3 then horacc end) as REG3,
       max(case when seq = 4 then horacc end) as REG4
  from R070ACCseq
  group by numcad, datacc;
```

Uma tabela é um conjunto de dados sem ordem. Se for necessário que para uma mesma data as colunas REG1 a REG4 listem os valores na ordem em que aparecem no exemplo, então é necessário que exista coluna que informe em qual ordem as linhas devem ser manipuladas.

---

> (...)  *tem como ficar no formato [hh:mm]*?

```
-- código #1 v4
set dateformat ydm;

with R070ACCseq as (
SELECT numcad, cast(datacc as date) as datacc, 
       convert(char(5), dateadd(minute, horacc, 0), 108) as horacc,
       seq= row_number() over (partition by numcad, cast(datacc as date) 
                               order by horacc)
  from R070ACC 
  where datacc between '2018-16-05' and '2018-15-06'
        and numcad = '2676' 
)
SELECT numcad, datacc, 
       max(case when seq = 1 then horacc end) as REG1,
       max(case when seq = 2 then horacc end) as REG2,
       max(case when seq = 3 then horacc end) as REG3,
       max(case when seq = 4 then horacc end) as REG4
  from R070ACCseq
  group by numcad, datacc;
```

Comment: @JeffersonLucena Acrescentado o "código #1 v4", com o tratamento de formato de horário.

Comment: Top José Diz... obrigado!

Answer (score 0):

```
with R070ACCseq as (
SELECT numcad, datacc, horacc,
       seq= row_number() over (partition by numcad, cast(datacc as date) 
                               order by datacc, horacc)
  from R070ACC   
  where datacc between ('2018-16-05') and ('2018-15-06')
        and numcad = '2676' 
)
SELECT numcad, datacc, 
       max(case when seq = 1 then CONVERT(VARCHAR, DATEADD(minute,horacc,0),108) end) as REG1,
       max(case when seq = 2 then CONVERT(VARCHAR, DATEADD(minute,horacc,0),108) end) as REG2,
       max(case when seq = 3 then CONVERT(VARCHAR, DATEADD(minute,horacc,0),108) end) as REG3,
       max(case when seq = 4 then CONVERT(VARCHAR, DATEADD(minute,horacc,0),108) end) as REG4 
  from R070ACCseq 
  group by numcad, datacc
```

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

José Diz, deu certo... ordenei pelos campos datacc, horacc e com isso ficou na sequência os registros de ponto, porém ao fazer a conversão de minutos para hora aparece os segundos, tem como ficar no formato [hh:mm]?