# Query SQL - colocar resultado em uma linha apenas

Tags: sql, query, sql-server-2012

```
SELECT pga.Titulo, e.Codigo
     FROM Qualidade_Diagrama_Processo_Grupo_Acao pga 
     JOIN Qualidade_Diagrama_Acao_Entidade ae on (ae.Id_Proc_Grupo_Acao = pga.Id)
     JOIN Qualidade_Diagrama_Entidade e on (e.Id = ae.Id_Entidade)
WHERE ae.Id_Proc_Grupo_Acao = 48
```

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Gostaria que o Resultado fosse em uma unica linha

Ex:
[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Comment: Tem algumas perguntas sobre *pivot table* aqui que podem ajudar, essa é uma: https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/307567/colocar-dados-de-uma-linha-em-colunas

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Fiz assim:

```
SELECT DISTINCT pga.Titulo,
               UPPER ( SUBSTRING ( ISNULL ( STUFF (
                                                     ( SELECT convert(varchar(10), c.Codigo) + ',' codigo
                                                      FROM Qualidade_Diagrama_Processo_Grupo_Acao a
                                                      JOIN Qualidade_Diagrama_Acao_Entidade b ON (b.Id_Proc_Grupo_Acao = a.Id)
                                                      JOIN Qualidade_Diagrama_Entidade c ON (c.Id = b.Id_Entidade)
                                                      WHERE b.Id_Proc_Grupo_Acao = ae.Id_Proc_Grupo_Acao
                                                        FOR XML PATH(''), TYPE ).value('.', 'NVARCHAR(MAX)'), 1, 0, '' ),
                                            ' ' ),1,
                                                  254 ) )
FROM Qualidade_Diagrama_Processo_Grupo_Acao pga
JOIN Qualidade_Diagrama_Acao_Entidade ae ON (ae.Id_Proc_Grupo_Acao = pga.Id)
WHERE ae.Id_Proc_Grupo_Acao = 48
```

## Resultado

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Answer (score 3):

Você precisa utilizar a [função de agregação STRING_AGG](https://docs.microsoft.com/pt-br/sql/t-sql/functions/string-agg-transact-sql?view=sql-server-2017):

```
SELECT 
    pga.Titulo, 
    STRING_AGG(e.Codigo,', ') as Codigos
FROM Qualidade_Diagrama_Processo_Grupo_Acao pga 
JOIN Qualidade_Diagrama_Acao_Entidade ae on (ae.Id_Proc_Grupo_Acao = pga.Id)
JOIN Qualidade_Diagrama_Entidade e on (e.Id = ae.Id_Entidade)
WHERE ae.Id_Proc_Grupo_Acao = 48
Group by pga.Titulo
```

Edit:

Após a informação do banco ser SQL Server 2012, e este não possuir a função String_AGG:

Você pode usar uma CTE (common table expressions) de forma recursiva:

Considerando a seguinte tabela:

```
create table tabela
(
  id integer,
  titulo varchar(10));

insert into tabela values (1, 'TESTE');
insert into tabela values (2, 'TESTE');
insert into tabela values (3, 'TESTE');
insert into tabela values (4, 'TESTE');
insert into tabela values (5, 'TESTE');
insert into tabela values (6, 'TESTE');
insert into tabela values (7, 'TESTE');
```

A query seria:

```
WITH CTE (Id, ids, titulos, LENGTH) AS
  (SELECT 0,
          CAST('' AS VARCHAR(8000)),
          CAST(t.titulo AS VARCHAR(8000)),
          0
   FROM tabela t
   GROUP BY t.titulo
   UNION ALL SELECT p.Id,
                    CAST(ids + CASE
                                   WHEN LENGTH = 0 THEN ''
                                   ELSE ', '
                               END + CAST(p.id AS VARCHAR(8000)) AS VARCHAR(8000)),
                    CAST(titulo AS VARCHAR(8000)),
                    LENGTH + 1
   FROM CTE c
   INNER JOIN tabela p ON c.titulos = p.titulo
   WHERE p.id > c.id )
SELECT ids,
       titulos
FROM
  (SELECT Id,
          ids,
          RANK() OVER (PARTITION BY titulos
                       ORDER BY LENGTH DESC), titulos
   FROM CTE) D (Id, ids, rank, titulos)
WHERE rank = 1 ;
```

> Resultado:

```
ids titulos
1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7 TESTE
```

Coloquei no [SQLFiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!18/3d5e9/13)

[Fonte](https://www.red-gate.com/simple-talk/sql/t-sql-programming/concatenating-row-values-in-transact-sql/)

Comment: estourou esse erro :Msg 195, Level 15, State 10, Line 27
'STRING_AGG' is not a recognized built-in function name.

Comment: versão SQLSERVER 2012 @DiegoRafaelSouza

Comment: Resposta Atualizada @DanielleArrudatorres